# Issues with the calculation of coefficient of determination in R

Tags: r, matrix, lm

I was playing around with R's `lm()` function and I noticed something odd when coming to the calculation of the [coefficient of determination R^2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination). So suppose I have a toy regression problem:

```
set.seed(0); N= 12;
x_ <- 1:N; y_ <- 2* x_+ rnorm(N, sd=2); 
lm1_ <- lm( y_ ~ x_ ); S1 <- summary(lm1_); 
lm2_ <- lm( y_ ~ -1 + model.matrix(lm1_) ); S2 <- summary(lm2_);
```

So at this point we are actually setting lm1_ and lm2_ being the same thing. The same dependent variable is used, the same model matrix is used and we should get the same exact fit. Let's check those:

```
identical( fitted(lm2_),fitted(lm1_))       
[1] TRUE                                    #SURE!
identical( residuals(lm2_), residuals(lm1_))
[1] TRUE                                    #YEAP!
identical( lm1_$df.residual, lm2_$df.residual)
[1] TRUE                                    #SORTED!
identical( as.numeric(model.matrix(lm2_ )), as.numeric(model.matrix(lm1_ ))) 
[1] TRUE                                    #WHY NOT?
identical( S2$r.squared, S1$r.squared)        
[1] FALSE                                   #HUH?
```

What happened? Let's go and used the definition from the wikipedia article for the *coefficient of determination* (or *percentage of variance explained* if you like):

```
1 - ((sum( residuals(lm1_)^2))/( sum( (y_ -mean(y_))^2)))
[1] 0.8575376
1 - ((sum( residuals(lm2_)^2))/( sum( (y_ -mean(y_))^2)))
[1] 0.8575376
identical(1 - ((sum( residuals(lm1_)^2))/(sum( (y_ -mean(y_))^2))), S1$r.squared)
[1] TRUE
identical(1 - ((sum( residuals(lm2_)^2))/(sum( (y_ -mean(y_))^2))), S1$r.squared)
[1] TRUE
identical(1 - ((sum( residuals(lm2_)^2))/(sum( (y_ -mean(y_))^2))), S2$r.squared)
[1] FALSE
S2$r.squared
[1] 0.9700402 # ???
```

Now apparently the whole trick get perplexed by the function `summary.lm()`. R^2 is calculate to be `mss/ (rss+ mss)` where `rss` is the Residual Sum of Squares `sum(residuals(lmX_)^2)`, and `mss` is the Mean Sum of Squares (fit) that is depend on the present of an intercept or not (c-p from summary.lm()):

```
mss <- if (attr(z$terms, "intercept")) 
            sum((f - mean(f))^2)
        else sum(f^2)
```

or in our case:

```
sum(scale(fitted(lm2_),scale=F)^2) / 
(sum(scale(fitted(lm2_),scale=F)^2)+sum(residuals(lm2_)^2))
[1] 0.8575376
sum(fitted(lm2_)^2) / (sum(fitted(lm2_)^2) + sum(residuals(lm2_)^2))
[1] 0.9700402
```

So clearly R did not identify the second model matrix as having an intercept. That though is a significant problem if as in my case someone is moving model matrices around. I know that the obvious fix will be to take the model matrix without the intercept but that does not alleviate the fact that this a design choice that is a bit prone to break. Wouldn't the more general definition save us this trouble with only a minor tweak? Is there some other obvious fix I can use do I don't bump into those problems?

This problem gets extremely severe if one is having not intercept and is using factor variables with interactions. Practically R might try and treat one of the levels as an intercept. Then the whole situation is just tragic:

```
library(MASS)
lm_oats <- lm( Y ~ -1+  V*N , oats)
S_oats <- summary(lm_oats)
S_oats$r.squared
[1] 0.9640413 # :*D
1-  ( sum( residuals(lm_oats)^2)  / sum( ( oats$Y- mean(oats$Y))^2 )  )
[1] 0.4256653 # :*(

#For the record:
sum((fitted(lm_oats))^2 )/(sum( residuals(lm_oats)^2) +sum((fitted(lm_oats))^2)) 
[1] 0.9640413
sum((scale(scale=F,fitted(lm_oats)))^2 ) /( sum( residuals(lm_oats)^2) 
+sum((scale(scale=F,fitted(lm_oats)))^2 )) 
[1] 0.4256653
```

Is this an R's design trait that somehow can be circumvented?
(I appreciate that my question quite open ended thanks for all those that made all the way down here!)

I am using R version 3.0.1, Matrix_1.0-12, lattice_0.20-15, MASS_7.3-26. (Linux 32-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been long discussions on the R mailing list about the non-sensibility/different meaning of R^2 for models that are forced through the intercept.  R tries to detect when you are fitting models without an intercept ("semantically", i.e. by looking for the presence of `-1` or `+0` in the model formula) and modifies the R^2 calculation accordingly.  If you do something tricky, you circumvent its attempt to do so.

More specifically:

- `summary.lm()` tests whether the `terms` element of the fitted model has an `intercept` attribute equal to 1
- the `terms` element of the fitted model is constructed by a call to `model.frame()`
- `model.frame()` calls `terms.formula`
- `terms.formula` calls some pretty hairy internal C code `C_termsform`, but you can see by trying out `terms(y~x-1)` vs `terms(y~x+0)` vs `terms(y~x)` that R is just checking semantically (as I suggested above ...)

Bottom line: if you want to do something fancy with model matrices that works around R's normal conventions, you should probably just go ahead and calculate R^2 according to your own preferred formula; you can copy the relevant code from `summary.lm()`.  If you are going this deep you might want to use `lm.fit()` instead, for computational efficiency.

Comment: Yup. For what it is worth, the `fastLm()` functions in RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen and RcppGSL do the same -- by looking whether there was an intercept in the formula or not.